Why decoder only model require left padding?
We used Gemma 2B model to infer, and tried left and right padding. "right" padding is giving us different answer compared to left padding.
Why do we use left padding for decoder only model, please provide technical answer.
I have also check
While fine-tuning a decoder only LLM like LLaMA on chat dataset, what kind of padding should one use? but there was no technical answer for it.

Did you ever figure this out? I'm also observing a similar issue with the same model in HuggingFace (well, gemma-2-2b-it to be exact). In my case, when I use padding_side=right, generation works. But when I use padding_side=left, generation doesn't work properly and keeps returning <pad> tokens. My understanding is that for decoder only models one should always use padding_side=right for training, and padding_side=left for inference. But in my case, both need to be right for some reason.
